# SSH manager like Tera Term Menu or SSHMenu for Ubuntu

Tags: ssh

I am looking for a ssh client that works like terraterm and has a menu where I can store the credentials of all the ssh server I want to access.
Some of the server s I log in have 50++ chars passwords, that are impossible to know by heart.

I found a screen-shot of the Terra term Menu on the net:

[image: img]

That's what I am crying for.

Do you have a hint?

[This is how Terra Term Menu looks like](http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/manual/en/usage/TTMenu/TTMenu.html)

---

I found `sshmenu` in `apt` but it crashes on start:

```
christian@christian:~$ sshmenu
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- sshmenu (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/bin/sshmenu:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You should not use passwords, unless you are being forced to do so.They are not safe.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but that was not the question.

Comment: What distribution and version of "linux" are you asking about exactly?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 13.10 now. But I be happy with any kind.

Comment: Not exactly what you ask, but **putty** for linux has a CLI ssh client that can accept passwords from command line argument. You can just create a script or alias or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bad news is that there doesn't exist a Linux version of Tera Term and SSHMenu doesn't work with (starting with Ubuntu 11.04 - Natty Narwhal).

The good news is that you can use your already installed **gnome-terminal** to accomplish what you wish. Yes, the default terminal in Ubuntu.

**You have to create a profile for each server where you want to connect.**

First you need to install [`sshpass`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sshpass/) - a tool for non-interactive ssh password authentication if you don't have it already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install sshpass
```

And now I will show you an example to illustrate how you must create a profile for one server where you will connect via ssh:

1. Open a Terminal and click on **File** → **New Profile**.
2. Type in the **Profile name** for the Profile such as the server where you want to connect.
3. After you click **Create** a new windou will pops up; go to the **Title and Command** tab.
4. Tick on **Update login record when command is launched**.
5. Tick on **Run a custom command instead of my shell**.
6. In the **Custom command** box add something like:

   ```
   sshpass -p "password" ssh user@hostname
   ```
7. **Close**.

[image: edit gnome-terminal profile]

From now you cat automatically connect to the desired server via ssh from gnome-terminal when you will open a  new window or new tab from the **File** menu:

[image: open a new tab with profile from gnome-terminal]

Thanks to **jjcv** for [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1743576&p=10756108#post10756108) from where I was inspired.

Comment: Nice idea, +1. Better warning that he has now all his password stored in clear in `.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/`; on the other hand, someone who forces you to use a 50+ length password and not accept private/public key authentication is asking for it...

Comment: OK the setting "When command exits" should be : "keep Terminal open." THe rest is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I would really advise a more secure, encrypted solution. Prepare a file, for example `mysshcmds` with this content:

```
sshpass -p "test1" ssh user@host1
sshpass -p "test2" ssh user@host2
sshpass -p "test3" ssh user@host3
```

(one command per line). Then encrypt it with `gpg`:

```
gpg -c mysshcmds
```

You will be asked for a password (twice). Now it will create an encrypted file `mysshcmds.gpg`. Delete the plain file.

To use it you can issue the command:

```
gpg -d mysshcmds.gpg 2> /dev/null | grep host1
```

which will print in clear the line:

```
sshpass -p "test1" ssh user@host1
```

which you can copy and past or even you can do

```
$(gpg -d mysshcmds.gpg 2> /dev/null | grep host1)
```

which will issue the command straight away. Or you can easily write  a script around it. This way you do not have any password stored in clear in your computer.

Note that the `2> /dev/null` is here to make `gpg` silent ... you can avoid it if you want.