# GUI SSH connection manager for Kubuntu

Tags: ssh, kubuntu, software-recommendation

I'm looking for an SSH connection manager with a GUI for Kubuntu.

[Is there an SSH connection manager?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21971/44876) and [SSH manager like Tera Term Menu or SSHMenu for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/440289/44876) are for Ubuntu.

---

E.g., on Windows there's PuTTY:

[image]

and WinSCP:

[image]

and on Ubuntu there's Remmina (uses GTK):

[image]

Comment: PuTTY exists on Ubuntu, you can install and use PuTTY if you want it.  I'm not sure there's a dedicated program for KDE though

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is a very old question but should any other wanderers come by, KDE's Konsole has a "SSH Manager" plugin:
[image: Konsole SSH Manager]

The only real compalaint I can level against it is it won't autopopulate from your `~/.ssh/config` file.